# How can I group by two variable in R taking mean of all other variables?

Tags: r, group-by

my data frame is:

| M1T1 | M1T2 | M1T3 | M2T1 | M2T2 | M2T3 | M3T1 | M3T2 | M3T3 | cntry_lan | admdw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | ATGER | group1 |
| 7 | 6 | 5 | NA | NA | NA | 6 | 6 | 5 | ATGER | group3 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | NA | NA | NA | 7 | 4 | 4 | ATGER | group2 |

My code is :

```
mtmm_data1  %>%
  group_by(cntry_lan) %>% group_by(admdw)
  summarise_at(vars(M1MT1, M1T2, M1T3, M2T1, M2T2, M2T3, M3T1, M3T2, M3T3), list(name = mean))
```

The error I get:

Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :
no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('quosures', 'list')"

Each countr_lan has three groups that are group1, group2 and group3. I would like to have one row for each country_lan and then have three groups for each country_lan having all the columns stable. Instead of creating new columns, I want to have the mean of the same columns M1T1-M3T3..

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I just forgot to put the codes I used. Now the error and the code is shared in the question.

Comment: try: `mtmm_data1  %>%
  group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), name = mean))`

Comment: This gives the following error: rror in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `name = mean`.
✖ `name` must be a vector, not a function.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: cntry_lan = "ATGER", admdw
  = "group1".
Backtrace:
 1. mtmm_data %>% group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>% ...
 3. dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(., across(everything()), name = mean)
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `aggregate`, you can use it this way :

```
aggregate(x=df[,c("M1T1","M1T2","M1T3","M2T1","M2T2","M2T3","M3T1","M3T2","M3T3")], #column on which you want to apply a function
          by=list(country=df$country,grp=df$grp),#grouping variables
          FUN=mean)#function to apply
```

`df` being your data frame

Comment: Many thanks NathanLVQ! It worked out. I am curious why the following code did not work `mtmm_data1  %>%   group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>%    summarise(across(everything(), name = mean))`

Comment: Variables also turned into NAs :/

Comment: Hi Korkut, this must be because your columns are not defined as numerical, you can fix it by computing this lines before the `aggregate` function : `mtmm_data1 = mtmm_data1 %>% mutate(across(everything(),as.character));
mtmm_data1$M1T1=as.numeric(mtmm_data1$M1T1);
mtmm_data1$M1T2=as.numeric(mtmm_data1$M1T2);`
...

Comment: I tried as you said, however, maybe another problem is that mtmm_data1 also has NAs. Would not follwing code do the same job? Well it did not work anyway :/

 `mtmm_data1 <- mtmm_data1 %>% mutate_at(c("M1T1","M1T2","M1T3","M2T1","M2T2","M2T3","M3T1","M3T2","M3T3"), as.numeric)`

Comment: Can you tell me what do R prompts when you are computing this line : `str(mtmm_data1)`

Comment: Also, it is normal for your code to return NA when you try to calculate the mean of values that include NAs. So you need to check if the NAs in the aggregate table match the NAs in your data. If all NAs in the aggregate table are due to NAs in your datas, then it is normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-data.frame(cntry_lan = c("ATGER"),
               admdw = c("group1", "group2", "group3"),
               M1T1 = c(NA,1,2),
               M1T2 = c(1,10,3),
               M1T3 = c(10,NA,1))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(c_across(starts_with("M")), na.rm=T), .keep="unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = admdw, values_from = mean)

#  cntry_lan group1 group2 group3
#  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 ATGER        5.5    5.5      2
```